# Getting image using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext

Tags: ios, drawing, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I am trying to understand, UIgraphicsGetImageContext() function, from my understanding, its a function, which gets the image from current bitmap context, so whenver I draw something on my canvas, and call this function, I get the image drawn, but suppose I dont draw anything then also it extracts an empty image. So I want to understand, how can we check when the canvas(CGContext) is nil.

Below is my code which I tried, but its not working

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO,0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    if(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"NIL");
    }
    else
    {   
        m_curImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSLog(@"%@",m_curImage);       
    }
```

So friends, please let me know how to get this it will be helpful to me

Regards
Ranjit

Comment: Sorry I know it's so old, but have you ever found the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will only return nil if the stack of graphics contexts is empty. In your drawing code you will always have a drawing context so it won't return nil here. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` pushes a new context on the stack.

You cannot use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to detect if you have drawn something in the context.

Comment: you cannot really check if something has been drawn (it may be drawn transparent or outside the bounds of the image, or the drawing is so small that it is invisible in the image), you can only check if the resulting image contains at least one pixel which is not fully transparent.

Comment: Oh is it?So @phix23, how can we check that?. I dont have any idea regarding this

Comment: you should not need to do this, re-think about your problem and re-design your code

Comment: Hi @phix23 I dont understand, If I dont draw anything then also I get a image which is empty.

Comment: yes of course, UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions always creates an image which will consume space even if it is empty

Comment: Ok and what does this line do   [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];?

Comment: Hey @phix23, can I check with touch events?

Comment: This line basically draws the view in the created image context. I can't help you anymore here...

Comment: I am stuck with a problem, hope you will help me out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727231/mutlitouch-drawing-in-ios